# enter activates link from text field

Tags: javascript, css, forms, hyperlink, textbox

I've looked through various questions on here and have not been able to find anything that will work for me, or I don't know what to edit it make it work.

I have a text box where the user will type something in and then they can either click the button or press enter and it will take them to specific page. I am simulating future functionality. I want it so that when the user presses enter or clicks the button it will go to the same page regardless of what they've typed.

Currently the button works, of course, but I can't figure out to get pressing enter to work. This is what I have so far in the HTML

```
<input type="text" class="search" form="form1" onfocus="if (this.value=='City, State') this.value='';" value="City, State"/>
<a href="Springfield.html"><img src="images/searchbutton.png" class="searchbutton"/></a>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest your elements in a `form`, and remove `form` attribute from `input`:

```
<form action="Springfield.html">
    <input type="text" class="search" onfocus="if (this.value=='City, State') this.value='';" value="City, State"/>
    <a href="Springfield.html"><img src="images/searchbutton.png" class="searchbutton"/></a>
</form>
```

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thank you so much. So it was just adding the form action that did it?